# How to create intermediate directories when required?

Tags: mkdir, phing

I've the following code to create directory from variable:

```
<mkdir dir="${project.private.dir}" />
```

But when user specifies directory where parent folder is missing, there is the error:

```
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/www/sites/default/private/files
Execution of target "set-dir-permissions" failed for the following reason: build.xml:192:18:
The file /var/www/sites/default/private/files does not exist
```

Directory `/var/www/sites/default` exists, but not the `private` yet and normally I would create by `mkdir`:

```
<exec command="mkdir -vp ${project.private.dir}" />
```

but this is not cross-compatible.

Is there any phing way of creating directory including intermediate as required similar to `-p` parameter for `mkdir`?

I couldn't find in for [MkdirTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/apbs22.html), maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1143, I can not reproduce this:

`<delete dir="foo" />
<mkdir dir="foo/bar/baz" />`

Successfully creates directory foo, with subdirectory bar, with subdirectory baz.

From your log it seems "/var/www/sites/default/private/files" is created as well, the "file does not exist" error seems to be coming from a subsequent step/task. Can you add the corresponding lines in your build file?